# Can deleted accepted answers still show the accepted tick?

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, deleted-answers

Currently, when an accepted answer is deleted, the accepted "tick" disappears, but it would be useful to know that a deleted answer was the accepted one.

Proposal:

If an accepted answer is deleted, and no other answer has since been accepted, show a (greyed out) acceptance tick next to the deleted answer.

---

Note: I am not suggesting a change to *who* can see deleted posts, just a small change to the information seen when viewing a deleted accepted answer.

Comment: @MonicaCellio visible to 10K etc. Not suggesting change to who can see deleted posts, just *what* they see

Comment: @MonicaCellio I've added a note to the question to clarify. It can't be a coincidence that two people have thought the same thing. cheers.

Comment: Not that I disagree with you, but *why* would it be useful? (I don't see any reason why it *shouldn't* be shown,  just trying to form a stronger argument for the dev time)

Comment: @RichardTingle because sometimes I've deleted an answer from the queue, which doesn't show if the answer is accepted, then had second thoughts and visited the question to have a good read, then I deleted the post to then be surprising that it was accepted. I know being accepted shouldn't influence whether to delete or not, but it does. Anyway, it's mysterious lost info and undeleting an accepted answer violates the "least astonishment" design principle.

Comment: ... I meant "then I *un* deleted"